# Обновление компонента React после удаления элемента

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Как правильно реализовать обновление React, не получается.

Есть такой код:

```
'use strict';

// tag::vars[]
const React = require('react');
const ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
const client = require('./client');
// end::vars[]

// tag::app[]
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {books: []};
        this.onDelete = this.onDelete.bind(this);
    }

    onDelete(book) {
        client({method: 'POST', path: 'http://localhost:8080/main/book/' + book.id + '/delete'}).done(response => {
            console.log('onDelete: ', book.id)
        });
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        client({method: 'GET', path: 'api'}).done(response => {
            console.info("componentDidMount response: %o", response);
            this.setState({books: response.entity});

        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <BookList books={this.state.books} onDelete={this.onDelete}/>
        )
    }
}
// end::app[]

// tag::book-list[]
class BookList extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        var books = this.props.books.map(book =>
            <Book key={book.id} book={book} onDelete={this.props.onDelete}/>
        );
        return (
            <table id="example" className="display nowrap" style={{width: '100%'}}>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Название</th>
                        <th>Автор</th>
                        <th>Издательство</th>
                        <th>Год издания</th>
                    </tr>
                    {books}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        )
    }
}
// end::book-list[]

// tag::book[]
class Book extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleDelete = this.handleDelete.bind(this);
    }

    handleDelete() {
        this.props.onDelete(this.props.book);
    }

    render() {
        const { id, name, author, publishing_house, the_year_of_publishing } = this.props.book;

        return (
            <tr>
                <td><a href={"http://localhost:8080/main/book/book?id=" + id}>{name}</a></td>
                <td onClick={() => { this.handleDelete() }}>{author}</td>
                <td>{publishing_house}</td>
                <td>{the_year_of_publishing}</td>
            </tr>
        )
    }
}
// end::book[]

// tag::render[]
ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('react')
)
// end::render[]
```

Книга удаляется на сервере, но на странице ничего не меняется - только после перезагрузки страницы. Как обновить this.state.books?

Answer (score 0):

Выправил, подправив метод:

```
onDelete(book) {
    client({method: 'POST', path: 'http://localhost:8080/main/book/' + book.id + '/delete'}).done(response => {
        console.log('onDelete: ', book.id);
        client({method: 'GET', path: 'api'}).done(response => {
            console.info("onDelete response: %o", response);
            this.setState({books: response.entity});
        });
    });
}
```

Если есть лучшая реализация, дайте, пожалуйста, знать.

Comment: мне кажется setState это как раз то, что нужно:)